# How to change interval of x-axis and represent them as strings, here name of month

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a array of size 365 number of days in a year. It has the average temperature of each day. Now I would like to plot it with X-axis as Months but represent all 365 days in plot.
By default is represents x -axis as interval of 50.

```
plt.plot(avg_Chile,'^',label="Chile")
legend(framealpha=0.5)
plt.xticks(["Mar","Apr","May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Feb"])
```

ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Comment: What about leap years that have 366 days?

Comment: The data that I am concerned with is of year 2013. So that's not a leap year.

Comment: Sure, but in the general case you should handle 366 days, once you get over this hurdle.

Comment: Well now the situation is If I don't use xticks it plots the graph with intervals of 50 and represent entire 365 days. First I need is to represent them on interval of 30 days. If I can get that it would be easy to do for 366 as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
xticks([0,30,60,90], ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar'])
```

See: [xticks documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=xticks#matplotlib.pyplot.xticks)